# Sending JSON to AJAX from Python Flask

Tags: javascript, python, json, ajax, flask

I'm trying to send data from a server made with Flask in Python, to the client and collect this data with AJAX. Many of the examples I have seen does this with jQuery, but I'd like to do it without jQuery. Is it possible to do this with just ordinary Javascript without jQuery, and how would I build this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the built in `XMLHttpRequest` object in javascript if you don't want to use jQuery. It's quite simple to use actually,

```
var url = 'www.yoursite.com/data.json';
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.open("GET", url, true);

xhr.onload = function() {
    console.log("Status Code", this.status);
    console.log("Body", this.response);
}
xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regular XmlhttpRequest: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Better yet, you can use the Fetch API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

From the MDN documentation:

```
 fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    console.log(myJson);
  });
```

Fetch makes use of Promise so you should use that.